Azure Notification Hub : Browser (Web Push)
I use SDK from MS and send message via API got message like this:
Postman and Azure Portal
"The Notification could not be delivered due to an unknown error".
SDK return my subscription and when I use external SDK like WebPush I got my notification in browser, but via Notification Hub cant get any notification.
Maybe somebody work with it and fix?
Request via Postman return
201 - Created
<NotificationOutcome xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"><Success>0</Success><Failure>1</Failure><Results><RegistrationResult><ApplicationPlatform>browser</ApplicationPlatform><PnsHandle>https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dD_bCEGT2V8:APA91bGaULueGvldUK-01iERuA7tdH9eWYM8sPpOHHVgNBvMEAuLz8M4cti5wfs2i61wBxzK36DtTu_v_18hh5kEH_SaeudjULOf-Z6i9g-Nih2dot5D_IjZziDGLy8XmyPcEbYEikWa</PnsHandle><RegistrationId>1339678898588419693-3314164189159452793-2</RegistrationId><Outcome>The Notification could not be delivered due to an unknown error</Outcome></RegistrationResult></Results></NotificationOutcome>

C# code for sending
 var browserNotification = new BrowserNotification(sampleNotificationContent);

 var directSendOutcome = await _hub.SendNotificationAsync(browserNotification,"tag");

I used different approached via MS Notification SDK and did not get any results.
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs
4.2.0

Postman will automatically add HTTP headers to the request while c# does not.  Postman has a control panel where you can get the entire request including the added headers.  Solution is to add the headers found in postman to your c# code.

Problem that sdk and request via postman got the same result and my browser did not receive any notifications

Webpush uses HTTPS (not HTTP) and uses a two step authentication where step 1 is to get a token and step 2 performs a query with the token.  See https://web.dev/articles/push-notifications-web-push-protocol  Postman probably switched code from http to https.

Have you worked with Azure Notification Hub?

No.  But done a lot with azure connections.

Here is the Gitub site with samples https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/main/NotificationHubSample

Web/Browser push support was trumpeted as being available back in March. But months later, we are all still waiting for it to be usable.

This could be related to FCM legacy being retired, Microsoft mentioned: FCM legacy APIs will no longer be supported and will be retired. To avoid any disruption in your push notification service, you must migrate to the FCM v1 protocol as soon as possible. Can anyone confirm?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-gcm-to-fcm

But in portal we have different provider for sending notification like:
Browser (Web Push)
Google (FCM v1)
